# Como remover espaços deixando apenas um?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Considerando uma variável com um texto no `SQL Server`. Como posso remover 2 ou mais espaços dentro do texto? Neste caso deixando apenas 1 espaço.

Por exemplo:

```
'1 tigre, 2  tigres, 3   tigres'
```

Deveria resultar em:

```
'1 tigre, 2 tigres, 3 tigres'
```

Comment: Você quer deixar somente 1 espaço ou nenhum?

Comment: @Marconi só 1 mesmo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
declare @texto varchar(MAX)
set @texto = '1 tigre, 2  tigres, 3   tigres'

set @texto = replace(replace(replace(@texto,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')
select @texto
```

Saída:

> 1 tigre, 2 tigres, 3 tigres

***Explicação:***

- Troque todos os espaços por `<>`. `replace(@texto,' ','<>')`, terá como resultado: ***1<>tigre,<>2<><>tigres,<>3<><><>tigres***
- Troque todos `><`por `''`. `replace('1<>tigre,<>2<><>tigres,<>3<><><>tigres','><','')`, terá como resultado: ***1<>tigre,<>2<>tigres,<>3<>tigres***
- Troque todos `<>` por espaços(`' '`). `replace('1<>tigre,<>2<>tigres,<>3<>tigres','<>',' ')`, resultará em: ***1 tigre, 2 tigres, 3 tigres***

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/5288)

***Nota:*** Replace funciona em praticamente todas as linguagens ou quase todas. Então essa solução pode ser aplicável a muitos caso.

## Update

Com o incentivo do @Jefferson Quesado e do Curso da Udemy sobre [Regexp](https://www.udemy.com/curso-regex) adicionei outro exemplo utilizando `Regex`.

1. Use a expressão regular `/[]{2,}/` para procurar duas ou mais ocorrências de espaços em branco.
2. Utilize `Replace` e substitua por nada.

Query:

```
declare @texto varchar(MAX)
set @texto = '1 tigre, 2  tigres, 3       tigres'

set @texto = replace(@texto,'','/[]{2,}/')
select @texto
```

## [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/5287)

Comment: Esse método é interessante porque funciona em, praticamente, qualquer linguagem

Comment: @Sorack sim já que o replace se encontra em quase todas as linguagens. Bom que pude ajudar :)

Comment: @Marconi, conhece de expressão regular em TSQL para resolver isso? Creio que se tiver possa resolver isso de maneira mais satisfatória, mais limpa de se ler, pelo menos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é um assunto ainda que tenho que estudar, mas tentei deixar o mais detalhado possível a resposta, colocando como cada replace terá como resultado. :)

Comment: Pode parecer uma marreta pra alguns, mas na minha opinião é uma forma simples e efetiva de resolver o problema!

Comment: Pelo que entendi da primeira solução se a string original contiver `><` eles serão perdidos ao final.